# My html css work fine in Codepen but doesn't look right when I open in my environment on Chrome

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cross-browser

My [codepen](http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/oxMQwE) looks how I'd like my view to look like but when I run the code in my environment it doesn't look right. I can't figure out whats different since I copied and pasted the same exact code. Im running it on Chrome and also using the codepen in chrome. Could this be some sort of browser compatibility issue though like if codepen is using some other browser engine to render the views. I put the views inside of an `Angular` template for a directive im using. I compile my site with `Grunt`.

## My Environment

[image]

## Codepen

[image]

HTML

```
<section id="ribbon">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="v-zigzag active">Mode 1</li>
    <li class="v-zigzag">Mode 2</li>
    <li class="v-zigzag">Mode 3</li>
    <li>Mode 4</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400);
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#ribbon {
  background: whitesmoke;
}
#ribbon ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#ribbon ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #757575;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#ribbon .v-zigzag {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #757575 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px, linear-gradient(135deg, #757575 5px, whitesmoke 0) 0 5px;
  background-position: right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}
#ribbon .v-zigzag:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, whitesmoke 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px, linear-gradient(135deg, whitesmoke 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  width: 10px;
  right: 3px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#ribbon .v-zigzag.active:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #03A9F4 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px, linear-gradient(135deg, #03A9F4 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  width: 10px;
  right: 3px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#ribbon .tabs .active {
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Did you try by disabling the extensions or running in InCognito mode? What about other browsers?

Comment: I just tried chrome incognito, safari and firefox, same issue. I have a feeling it may be an oveerride occuring because most styles are being correctly applied. I tried adding bootstrap to my codepen but that didnt break anything.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26922098

Comment: I saw this but I'm sure that I'm using scss

Answer (score 0):

You should compare your compiled output with the compiled output on codepen.io. I suspect that you may not use the same CSS preprocessor (SCSS) as codepen or maybe another version.

I ran the compiled css and html from codepen locally and everything worked.

Comment: how do I view compiled css?

Comment: Of your code or on codepen?
On codepen you can press "view compiled" to see it and your code would be visible compiled in your browser console (f12 usually)

Comment: No of my code from environment, Im using grunt to compile

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the `section` tag which was applying some additional styles created by my environment `angular-fullstack-generator`.